# concatenate two columns in specific format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have the below line of my query,

```
concat(fiscalyear,fiscalweek) as yearweek,
```

week 1 of year 2016 is displayed as 20161, however I need it to display as 201601, and week 10 would look like 201610,

how do I format the column fiscalweek ?

please don't shoot me down I am very new

Comment: Tag your database

Comment: which database are you using and what are the datatypes of "fiscalyear" and "fiscalweek"?

Comment: im using Microsoft SQL serve management studio, and they are both as numbers

Comment: and what is "fiscalyear" and "fiscalweek" column data types ?

Comment: both columns are integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer of JaydipJ.
As both columns are of type `Integer` you have to cast both in `Varchar` data type.

And updated answer should be like

```
SELECT convert(varchar(15),fiscalyear)+''+RIGHT('0'+convert(varchar(15),fiscalweek),2) as yearweek
```

Comment: Works perfect, Thank You

Comment: Well, I just missed that part of conversion of data types. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, then <kbd>[RIGHT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql)</kbd> function may help to get desire result

```
SELECT fiscalyear+''+RIGHT('0'+fiscalweek,2) as yearweek,
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Oracle you can try this:

```
select case when fiscalweek between 1 and 9 then concat(fiscalyear,'0'||fiscalweek) else concat(fiscalyear,fiscalweek) end from yourTableName
```

In case statmemt I am checking whether fiscalweek is one digit number and based on that using concat() function, constructing the output.

Answer (score 0):

If the fiscalweek column is already a string , JaydipJ solution will work. Otherwise you can try the following to get the result:

```
SELECT  concat(fiscalyear, RIGHT('0' + cast(fiscalweek as varchar(2)),2))as yearweek ,
```